# .NET sending email attachment with custom Mime type

Tags: c#, edifact

I need to create an email message with an attachment. The attachment contains a EDIFACT message.I need to define a custom Mime type for this attachment or something. I need to define a Mime Type application/x-EDIORDER. The .net provided mime types doesnt contain this mime type. How can I do this? I am using C# for sending the messages.

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend to transfer EDIFACT message using AS2, and not e-mail. E-mail is the worst - most unreliable- transport protocol you can use to transfer electronic messages!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify any Mime ContentType by creating a new instance of [Mime.ContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mime.contenttype.aspx) for example:

```
Mail.Attachment attach = New Mail.Attachment(attachmentData, New Mime.ContentType("application/x-EDIORDER"));
```

For a few content types (such as HTML) you may find that you need to add it as a [LinkedResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.linkedresource.aspx) that is an  [AlternateView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.alternateview.aspx) rather than attaching it as a regular attachment however I am unfamiliar with EDIORDER.

Answer (score 2):

You can [use System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dk1fb84h.aspx) Namespace to achieve this. The [`Attachment.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.aspx) property allow to set the MIME content type value in the content type associated with this attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by adding the following code:

```
            ContentType ct = new ContentType("application/x-EDIORDER");

            Attachment data = new Attachment(EdiFile, ct);
```